# Visual Studio 2013 ASP.Net Publish ConnexionString

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, web-config, connection-string, publish

When i publish my ASP.Net project (ftp method), web.config does not contain connexionstring section.

Do you know how i can do to make ASP.Net upload connexionstrings on production web.config ?

Or should i do this by hand ?

Comment: Did you use web.config transformation ? Try publishing under debug first .And for Prouction ,make sure that you are building project under production/live configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is url for web.config transformation.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations